# Offline access to MoinMoin wiki using Google Gears

Tags: python, wiki, offline, google-gears, moinmoin

How to add offline access functionality to [MoinMoin wiki](http://moinmo.in)?

As a minimum, I would love to have browsing access to all pages on a server-based wiki  (while being offline). Search and other things, which do not modify the content, are secondary. An added bonus would be if this solution allowed to update wiki content while offline and push it back to the wiki when online.

Google Gears looks like a good candidate for trying to solve this, but other solutions are also welcome.

An interesting property of MoinMoin is that it keeps content in regular files instead of the database. This can make it easier to port wiki content from one location to another, but I don't know if that can play any role in answering this question.

Note: if you see a good reply please rate it up. i'd love to do that, but the site does not let me do ratings yet.

Comment: I would install the same moinmoin version on the computer you use offline and rsync the entire data directory from the server to the laptop.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good idea. What about ability to do updates? You could do two-way rsync but there is a risk of loosing data if the server was updated while you were offline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*By using Gears with the Firefox Greasemonkey plugin, you can inject Gears code into any website that you want. Don't wait for your favorite website to enable offline support -- do it yourself.* http://code.google.com/apis/gears/articles/gearsmonkey.html

Comment: Does the Gears Offline Wikipedia script (from the URL you gave) work for you? I am getting an error message "The page at http://en.wikipedia.org says:
Problem in initializing Gears: unsafeWindow.GearsFactory is not a function"

Answer (score 2):

If you have the freedom to change the wiki software, I might suggest looking at [ikiwiki](http://ikiwiki.info). You can set it up so the pages are backed by a real VCS such as Git, in which case you can clone the whole wiki and read and even update it offline.

Comment: ikiwiki's approach of using a (D)VCS underneath is interesting and would make offline or even distributed wikis much easier to create. however, I like MoinMoin and would like to solve the "offline access" question w/o switching wiki software first.

Answer (score 1):

If you're patient enough, MoinMoin release 2.0 will ship with Mercurial DVCS backend, so you won't have to switch. More info on http://moinmo.in/MoinMoin2.0

Answer (score 1):

- if you want to do that on servers see HelpOnSynchronisation in moinmoin + DesktopEdition
- if locally, use  [unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/)  + DesktopEdition . be careful to ignore cache and such. this will allow 2-way synchronisation.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at [MoinMoin Desktop Edition](http://moinmo.in/DesktopEdition).

Comment: The Desktop Edition is just a wiki which you can run locally. It is easy to install and has a web server built-in but this won't solve the original problem of offline access to a web-based wiki.

However, it might work in combo with rsync solution suggested in @codeape's comment to the question.

Comment: Note that the desktop edition isn't available in newer versions of Moin.  Plus, I don't think this is quite the answer he was looking for as I'm assuming the instance of Moin is on another computer.